# Codeigniter: How to pass multiple datas (like arrays AND single data) from a controller to a view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have here:

```
  public function index()
{
    $this->is_logged_in();
    $this->load->model('ReportModel');
    $this->load->model('ConsultantModel');

    if (isset($_POST['report'])){
        $reports=$this->ReportModel->search($_POST['report']); 
    } else {
        $reports=$this->ReportModel->get_last_ten_entries();
    }

    $models=$this->ReportModel->getModel();
    $terms=$this->ReportModel->getTerm();

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['query'] = $this->ConsultantModel->getConsultantData($username);

    //i want to send data to the report list view
    //$this->load->view('report/reportlist', $data);
    $this->load->view('report/reportlist', array('reports'=>$reports,'terms'=>$terms,'models'=>$models));
}
```

i want to pass both the array and the data in a single view (report/reportlist). i know that its possible because its very a simple idea but i don't know how. even if it can't, i know you guys know some tricks. please if you know, answer this.

Comment: What is your problem ? You already pass multiple datas to your view. Just replace $data['query'] by $query, and pass it with others variables.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it OP did not search before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[codeigniter]+is%3Aquestion+from+a+controller+to+a+view

Comment: Thank you vincent, i just want to pass $data['query'] to the reportlist view. how do do that? i already passed an array.

Comment: ive searched already but it doesnt seem to answer my question. so i asked here. @tereško

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index()
{
    $this->is_logged_in();
    $this->load->model('ReportModel');
    $this->load->model('ConsultantModel');

    $data = array();
    if (isset($_POST['report'])){
      $data['reports'] = $this->ReportModel->search($_POST['report']); 
    } else {
      $data['reports'] = $this->ReportModel->get_last_ten_entries();
    }

    $data['models'] = $this->ReportModel->getModel();
    $data['terms'] = $this->ReportModel->getTerm();

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data['query'] = $this->ConsultantModel->getConsultantData($username);

    $this->load->view('report/reportlist', $data);
}
```

**You can use as following in your views -**

**1) Reports -**

i) If single value -

```
echo $reports;
```

ii) If an array

```
foreach($reports as $report)
{
    echo $report[..];
}
```

Similarly for rest.

Comment: thank you. but sir won't i get the value of $reports because it is not loaded in the controller?

Comment: i just want to load $this->load->view('report/reportlist', $data, array('reports'=>$reports,'terms'=>$terms,'models'=>$models));

but i dont know the proper syntax.

Comment: and everytime i do that, the array is not loaded.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. Use are using $this->load->view('{viewname}',''{data},'{data}').

Comment: Correct syntax would be $this->load->view('{viewname}','{data}')

Comment: i solve this using this: $data['data']=$data;
        $data['reports']=$reports;
        $data['terms']=$terms;
        $data['models']=$models;
        $this->load->view('report/reportlist', $data); but thanks anyway guys!